# C# DataGridView Cell Format Mask not works

Tags: c#, datagridview, format

I put the following format in the "Format" field of the "DefaultCellStyle" option: `##.###.###/####-##`

Value: `12123123123412`

Result wanted: `12.123.123/1234-12`

But in practice the formatting does not apply.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: write the code you used? what value are you getting?

Comment: I am not using a specific code. I am using the Visual Studio option.
The formatting is not applied, so the returned value is the same as that typed in the field.
Thank you.

Comment: When you set the value `12123123123412` what is the type (String, Int, Decimal, Double, Object)?

Comment: The value type is String.